# Deserialize json shows null in xamarin forms

Tags: json, xamarin.forms

Hi I have a Login API which I am using to login though my xamarin.forms app.
I will post my username and password and in return I am getting some data.Now Iam facing some issues at deserialization of json. Iam getting data at my resultJson but I cant deserialize it. Help me.

My Json :

```
[
{
"Result":true,
"ID":"fc938df0",
"LoginName":"test",
"UserName":"test",
"ConnectionString":"MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Test1;User ID=db;Password=db@2018",
"UserProfileID":"fc938df0"
}
]
```

**My API Call class which have deserialization of Json.**

```
    public T APICallResult<T>()
        {
            try
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    if (loadingIndicator != null)
                    {
                        loadingIndicator.IsRunning = true;
                        loadingIndicator.IsVisible = true;
                    }
                });
                var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiurl);
                req.Content = new StringContent(postdata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                string stringObtained = "";

                Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () => await Threading(client, req));
                task.Wait();
                stringObtained = task.Result;

                var jsonObtained = Regex.Unescape(stringObtained);
                int startIndex = jsonObtained.IndexOf('[');
                int endIndex = jsonObtained.LastIndexOf(']');
                int length = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
                var resultJSON = jsonObtained.Substring(startIndex, length);


                T resultObject;//Generic type object
                try
                {

//**Deserializing**
                    resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultJSON);//, settings);  
                    removeLoadingAnimation();
                    return resultObject;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    List<ErrorMessageData> errorMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ErrorMessageData>>(resultJSON);
                    errorMessage = errorMessages[0];
                    removeLoadingAnimation();
                    return default(T);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errorMessage = new ErrorMessageData();
                errorMessage.Flag = false;
                errorMessage.Message = e.Message;
                removeLoadingAnimation();
                return default(T);
            }
        }
```

**My API call at login class**

```
string postdataForLogin = "{\"userName\":\"" + userName.Text + "\",\"password\":\"" + password.Text + "\",\"RequestURL\":\"" + CommonValues.RequestURL + "\"}";
        APICall callForLogin = new APICall("/API/LoginMobile/HomeLogin", postdataForLogin, loadingIndicator);           
        try
        {
            List<LoginData> resultObjForLogin = callForLogin.APICallResult <List<LoginData>>();       
            if (resultObjForLogin != null)
            {


                LoginData loginData = new LoginData();
                loginData = resultObjForLogin[0];
                Settings.userID = loginData.UserProfileID;
                Settings.connectionString = loginData.ConnectionString;
                if (loginData.Result)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {                         
                        Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
                        await Navigation.PopAsync();
                    });
                }
```

**My DataModel**

```
  public class LoginData
    {

         public bool Result { get; set; }            
         public string ID { get; set; }
         public string UserProfileID { get; set; }
         public string LoginName { get; set; }
         public string UserName { get; set; }
         public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception ? If not what value do you get in resultObject ?

Comment: The result object is null..But iam getting value at resultJson

Comment: Can you try this :LoginData  resultObject;
                try
                {
                    resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< LoginData >(resultJSON);//, settings);
                    removeLoadingAnimation();
                    return resultObject;
                }

Comment: I am using generic type as return type

Comment: Could you please strip down your code to a [mcve]. It's hard to tell what went wrong with that many movable parts. Furthermore, have you checked that the text in `resultJSON` is the exact JSON that you have given? Did you catch any exceptions in the nested `try/catch` block? Where exactly does the function return?

Comment: @PaulKertscher Thanks for the suggestion bro. There is no excepton. The resultJson didnt deserialize to resultObject

Comment: @AndroDevil Strange. I've tried to boil your code down to just the deserialization (passing your JSON as a `string` parameter) and it did deserialize correctly.

Comment: are you sure your generic is deserializing to type `LoginData` and not something else?

Comment: @G.hakim bro its List<LoginData>

Comment: @PaulKertscher Bro what will be the problem in my case?

Comment: Shouldn't it be LoginData and not List<LoginData>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems strange, My problem solved after downgrading my xamarin.forms from latest version to pre release 4.0.0.169046- pre5. I think its a xamarin forms bug